# How to surround a square box with content as a search-icon in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a screenshot as shown below which I am trying to replicate in HTML and CSS.

[image]

At this moment, I am able to replicate this in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/23/embedded/result/).

The HTML and CSS code which I have used in order to make the search icon is:

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="nav-top-searchbar">
    <form>
        <span class="fa fa-search searchicon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <input type="text" name="search">
        <div style="">
            <img tabindex="1" src="https://s9.postimg.org/d6s4xvykv/Ellipsis.png" id="ellipsis">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">View Status</a><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>
                <li><a href="#">Release Bills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add Attendee</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Export as</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">View in Google Sheets</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Send Notifications</a></li>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
    border: 1px #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes do I need to make in the above CSS codes so that `square box with content as search-icon gets displayed across the search-icon as show above in the screenshot`. I tried using border in CSS but I am not able to achieve the desired design.

Comment: U need to add the border style, example "border-style: solid;". or "border: 1px solid #FFFFFF".

Answer (score 0):

CSS Borders require a `border-style` property.

Try `border: 1px solid #fff;`

According to the <kbd>[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border)</kbd>, the default style is actual set to `none`, hence why it's invisible until you define a style.

Note, you'll need to add some padding as well to get the border off of the icon a bit like your example. Also of note is that borders automatically inherit the color property, so you could theoretically just use `border: 1px solid;` if you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you update it in the fiddle ? I tried with your CSS code but somehow it doesn't match the exact design.

Answer (score 0):

update your css code with these lines:

```
.searchicon {
float: left;
margin-top: -20px;
position: relative;
top: 26px;
left: 8px;
padding: 3px;
color: white;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Try this, You can solve the problem.

Comment: @A. Sakkeer Thanks for the CSS code. Can you update it in the fiddle ? I tried your CSS codes but it didn't match the design.

Comment: @ user5447339 - Sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define border style too..`border: 1px solid white;` and some `padding`..

```
.searchicon {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 27px;
    left: 8px;
    color: white;
     border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 3px;

}
```

As given in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/39/)

Comment: Thanks for the CSS code. Just out of curiosity, I am wondering should I be using `position: relative` or `position: absolute` ?

Comment: using position: absolute would give you more flexibility than position: relative, because with absolute you would be able to position the div with left, top, right and bottom attribute

Answer (score 0):

You have incomplete value in border property. Try this code to get your desired result.

```
.searchicon {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    color: white;
     border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the CSS code. Just out of curiosity, I am wondering should I be using position: relative or position: absolute ?